# Progress Dialog Freezes while switching to another activity

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have two activities. While switching to second activity by intent, it takes 3-4 seconds because it has lots of components with adapters fetching data from SQLite etc. Thus, I want to show a progress dialog while switching.

I have been digging topics for this purpose and tried many of them:

1-) Using AsyncTask on the second activity. It doesn't show the progress dialog as soon as I click on a component to switch to the second activity. It waits for 3-4 seconds and then progress dialog shows up for less then a second which is not user-friendly way.

2-) Using AsyncTask on the first activity. It shows as soon as I click on that component but the progress wheel doesn't spin. The progress dialog freezes.

3-) Using AsyncTask onStart() method on the second activity. This results as the first way.

The code below implements the second way above, using AsyncTask on the first activity.

```
public void toVisitRegister(Event event) { //Switching to the second activity
    new startingThread().execute();
    Intent toVisitRegister = new Intent(MainCalendar.this, VisitRegister.class);
    startActivity(toVisitRegister);
    finish();
}
```

And here is the AsyncTask

```
public class startingThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        startingProgress = new ProgressDialog(MainCalendar.this);
        startingProgress.setTitle("Visit Register");
        startingProgress.setMessage("Initializing...");
        startingProgress.show();
        }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(MainCalendar.this.startingProgress != null) {
            MainCalendar.this.startingProgress.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to call startActivity in onPostExecute, but it didn't work. Therefore, I am waiting for your opinions and suggessions about this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I also tried to call startActivity in onPostExecute,
```

Pass the Activity context to `startingThread AsyncTask` and put your start activity code in `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(MainCalendar.this.startingProgress != null) {
            MainCalendar.this.startingProgress.dismiss();
            Intent toVisitRegister = new Intent(MainCalendar.this, VisitRegister.class);
            mContext.startActivity(toVisitRegister);
            mContext.finish();
        }
    }
```

Here `mContext` is the Context of your current `MainCalendar` Activity.

Comment: As soon as I click on the component to switch, progress dialog showed up less than a second. Then, I put the dismiss() below the finish(), but this time progress wheel didn't spin. Also finish() method is undefined for the mContext.

Comment: cast mContext to Activity. like, `((Activity)mContext).finish();`

Comment: Also check your `VisitRegister` Activity is there any heavy work  done in the `onCreate()` or `onStart()` of it?

Comment: VisitRegister is really a heavy activity. I tried do these heavy work onStart() method but it didn't work well. So how can us approach these heavy activity?

Comment: Actually, your main problem is heavy work on **VisitRegister** activity. Start `AsyncTask` in `onCreate()` of **VisitRegister** and do all heavy work in `AsyncTask` when it completes update the `VisitRegister UI`. So then time taken on switching Activity become less.

Comment: I tried the implementation and it worked, not very satisfying but your approach is true. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your implementation, the AsyncTask wont have time to work because you will be jumping to the next Activity right away. Try calling the next activity in PostExecute().

```
I also tried to call startActivity in onPostExecute, but it didn't work.
```

Did you did it like this:

```
public void toVisitRegister(Event event) { //Switching to the second activity
    new startingThread().execute();
}

public class startingThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        startingProgress = new ProgressDialog(MainCalendar.this);
        startingProgress.setTitle("Visit Register");
        startingProgress.setMessage("Initializing...");
        startingProgress.show();
        }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         if(MainCalendar.this.startingProgress != null) {
            MainCalendar.this.startingProgress.dismiss();
        }
    Intent toVisitRegister = new Intent(MainCalendar.this, VisitRegister.class);
    startActivity(toVisitRegister);
    finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did, but the progress dialog showed up less than a second and application waited for seconds to switch.

Comment: What do you do in the VisitRegister activity onCreate() method?

Comment: Filling seven Spinners by one adapter using interface with tremendous data fetched from SQLite, and an AutoCompleteTextView by another adapter. Controlling if these component be set selection. So VisitRegister is a quite heavy activity.

Comment: Try to load those heavy task inside a AsyncTask

Comment: I tried the implementation and it worked, not very satisfying but your approach is true. Thanks.